# Invertibility as Criteria for a Loop

Tags: abstract-algebra, divisibility, inverse, magma, quasigroups

I try to understand the correct criteria for a Loop.
I see in Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element#In_a_unital_magma
that *“A unital magma in which all elements are invertible is called a loop”*
Also in the answer to this question:
[What's the difference between a monoid and a group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146887/whats-the-difference-between-a-monoid-and-a-group)
Loop *“is equivalent to asking that conditions 2 and 3 be satisfied, but not condition 1”* meaning Existence of neutral element and Existence of inverses are sufficient for a Loop.
However here:
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quasigroup
*“Note that, in the absence of associativity, it is not enough (even for a loop) to say that every element has an inverse element (on either side); instead, you must say that division is always possible”*
Can someone tell if there is any inaccuracy in one of the sites above or that I miss something?